# Sugar daddy giving his bank account info

Tags: scams, paypal, sugar-daddy

Theres an app to find snapchat friends. And there is a guy wanting to be my sugar daddy. We havnt met let alone even talked. And he asks if he can trust me. And i say yes. So he gives me his bank account information to pay of credit in paypal. Im pretty sure its gotta be a scam. But i just wanted to say what you guys think.

Comment: Why would someone want to be a sugar daddy for someone he hasn’t met? A sugar daddy is someone who gives you money for no reason.

Comment: A sugar daddy is someone who gives you money in return for...certain favours. A sugar daddy who gives you money for no reason is called a scammer.

Comment: Yup, it is either a scam our outright prostitution. Neither option sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a scam. It isn't *his* bank account info, it's some other unlucky person's and he needs your fingerprints over the withdrawals from it rather than his own. Delete the messages, block him and move on.